# issue with running sql through odbc connection in excel

Tags: sql, excel, odbc

i am trying to run sql code in excel but only first line of the code runs rest other lines are ignored and gives result as zero

need help how to solve this

Comment: if you provide the code, it will be much easier to help and also describe the context it is running in

Comment: okay the problem solved but have another issue with the code. so there are two different codes for two data pull i want to combine the two codes to give the result in consolidated format